# Rails - Partial render receives wrong object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am currently rendering a list of posts like this:

`<%= render partial: "layouts/modules/forums/posts/post", collection: @topic.posts %>`

This works fine. However, inside the _post.html.erb, I call

`<%= render partial: "layouts/users/name", user: post.user %>`

This renders the name, but it kinda reuses the first object it gets. To help explain, I added some debug:

`<% puts("_post user: "+post.user.name) %>` in the _post.html.erb and a similar puts in the _name erb. (The _post puts is before the _name render).
This are the results:

```
_name user: User1
_post user: User1
_name user: User1
_post user: User2
_name user: User1
```

Why does it do this? You would expect that 1. _post comes before _name, and 2. When you pass in post, it uses the post, and not one it got before.

Can you explain this to me, and maybe provide me with a solution for the problem I have?
Thank you!

Comment: how is post being past into the _post.html.erb file, at all?

Comment: @rogerdpack I provided that line, `<%= render partial: "layouts/modules/forums/posts/post", collection: @topic.posts %>` renders the _post.html.erb page

Comment: what if you do it like render...:as => :post ? what is the value of @topic.posts ?

Comment: Might need to see a bit more code...

Comment: When you render `layouts/users/name`, shouldn't the argument `user: post.user` instead be written as `locals: {user: post.user}`...?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you should include the posts when you find the topic, 
`Topic.find(params[:topic_id]).includes(:posts)`
that solves n+1 query problem